# exchange routes and prefixes of remote clients in the mpls

Tags: cisco, mpls

is it possible to exchange routes and prefixes of remote clients in the mpls by an ospf? to avoid creating each time BGP sessions between PEs especially when the topology is scalable

Comment: Do the *remote clients* belong to your network administration or are they independent? OSPF doesn't provide much security and as an IGP it requires a high level of trust.

Comment: Based on experience, it is not a good idea to run OSPF over long distances. It can work, but convergence times are greatly extended, sometimes leaving your network unstable for extended periods. Switching to BGP solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use OSPF between the PE and CE, but you have to take care since the MPLS network breaks the backbone area.

BGP is a very scalable protocol -- more so than OSPF.  It runs the Internet with almost a million routes.